# Can't use ChangeWindowMessageFilter from user32.dll in python

Tags: python, dll, drag-and-drop

I'm try to call functions **ChangeWindowMessageFilter** in a dll(**user32.dll**)

```
dlluser32 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('user32.dll')
dlluser32.ChangeWindowMessageFilter(0x0233, 1)
dlluser32.ChangeWindowMessageFilter(0x0048, 1)
dlluser32.ChangeWindowMessageFilter(0x0049, 1)
```

Results in:

```
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (16 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
```

How do I get the call right ?
I want use this functions to enable drag and drop for my app when run in window, if it does not work, have another way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set calling conversion:

```
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, DWORD, UINT

dlluser32 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('user32.dll')
ChangeWindowMessageFilter = dlluser32.ChangeWindowMessageFilter

# BOOL WINAPI ChangeWindowMessageFilter(_In_  UINT message, _In_  DWORD dwFlag);
ChangeWindowMessageFilter.restype = BOOL
ChangeWindowMessageFilter.argtypes = (UINT, DWORD)

# Now you can call it there...
```